# MongoDB date time format

Tags: .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am inserting data in MongoDB from my .NET website using `DateTime.Now`. When I then select a record from MongoDB, it returns a date like this: `{"CreatedOn" : "/Date(1420178662748+0530)/"}`.

Please tell me how I can compare with the current date. I'm also not able to convert it to  `MMM dd yyyy hh:mm:ss` format .

This is my JSON string which I insert in MongoDB:

```
{
    "CreatedOn":"\/Date(1420203027378+0530)\/",
    "Details":"",
    "IP":"127.0.0.1",
    "Message":"data goingThe login method",
    "Module":"UI",
    "Name":"Page_Load",
    "Product":"RevGain",
    "Type":"INFO",
    "UserId":"1003"
}
```

Comment: Please edit your post to include the code you have implemented, a sample collection in the database after the insert and your desired output. That way your question shall gain more attention.

Comment: You need to insert your date as a `ISODate` or `Date` object and not a String, With the current way you have stored, it is not possible to do a date comparison.

Comment: thankyou so much, i got it now i am converting string date into datetime format before inserting into mongodb